# Angularjs View Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have a view template that has a `model` that is a service's attribute, set in a directive's controller. When the service's attribute is updated, it is not updated in the view.

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="i in x">
   <item model=i></item>
 </li>
```

```
app.directive('x', function($http, MyService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "partials/list.html",
        controller: function($scope, MyService){
            $scope.x = MyService.x;
        }
    }
});
```

The only way I can get the model to reflect the change is if the directive's controller has the Service update the attribute — but at the time the controller is called, I don't yet have the data.

What to do? Should I be somehow explicitly calling the directive's controller, or break out the logic that's in that controller? Neither seems very angular.

I'm missing part of the puzzle, aren't i? How to have `$scope.x` updated as `MyService.x` as if it were a reference, not a literal?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put some code to understand your problem :) ?

Comment: Will do, though not sure it'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your `$scope.x` and `MyService.x` should point to same array at any given time. The best way is to initialize the array once in the service with `[]`.

After that always to `push` and `slice` operations to add and remove elements from the array.

This issue can come when the binding are set on a different array and the service is pointing to a different array.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response. I should sleep more!
`
    this.x.length = 0; 
    newValues.forEach(
      function(i){ 
        this.x.push(i) 
      }, this);
`